# ggplot legend based on axis colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, yaxis, geom-tile

I am trying to create a legend in ggplot based on the color of the y axis I have set.

Does anyone know if a way to manually create a legend based off of data not present in  the figure itself?

Below is a toy example of the plot and code. In this plot, I have graphed student grades on 3 different days. The names of the students are colored based on which class they are in. I would like to know whether I can add an additional legend showing "Class A" in green and "Class B" in purple. [image]

As an additional note, I realize that the days are not in order. I am not worried about this as the moment.

Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)

name <- c("Mike", "Mike","Mike",
          "Sam","Sam","Sam", 
          "Max","Max","Max", 
          "Sarah","Sarah","Sarah") 
date <- c("Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday",
          "Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday",
          "Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday",
          "Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday")
grade <- c(100, 98, 93, 
           92, 64, 90, 
           80, 88,70,
           90,94,100)
classroom <- c("Class A", "Class A","Class A", 
               "Class A", "Class A","Class A", 
               "Class B", "Class B","Class B", 
               "Class B", "Class B","Class B")

df <- data.frame(cbind(name, date, grade, classroom)) %>%
  mutate(grade = as.integer(grade),
         classroom = as.factor(classroom))


plot <- ggplot(df, aes(y=name, x=date, fill= grade < 90)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(name = " ", values = c( "turquoise3","lightgrey"), labels = c("Above 90","At or below 90" )) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = ifelse(levels(df$classroom) %in% "Class A", "Green", "Purple"))) +
  guides(size = "none", color = "none", alpha = "none")
```

Comment: You might be able to use [ggtext](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext)

Answer (score 0):

You could `facet_wrap`

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(y=name, x=date, fill= grade < 90)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(name = " ", values = c( "turquoise3","lightgrey"), labels = c("Above 90","At or below 90" )) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = ifelse(levels(df$classroom) %in% "Class A", "Green", "Purple"))) +
  guides(size = "none", color = "none", alpha = "none") 

plot +  facet_wrap(~classroom)
```

[image]

OR `facet_grid`

```
plot + facet_grid(rows = vars(classroom))
```

[image]